# Using DAO recordset addnew in a multiple user environment

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am writing an excel macro that can automatically add new entries to an Access database.

In the event that multiple users simultaneously press the button to execute the Excel macro (shown below), will Access be able to automatically update the database and avoid any conflicts?

A sample code I plan to use:

```
Function AddName(rstTemp As Recordset, _ 
 strFirst As String, strLast As String) 

 ' Adds a new record to a Recordset using the data passed 
 ' by the calling procedure. The new record is then made 
 ' the current record. 
 With rstTemp 
 .AddNew 
 !FirstName = strFirst 
 !LastName = strLast 
 .Update 
 .Bookmark = .LastModified 
 End With 

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem so long as two or more users **don't** update the same record in the same table simultaneously.

You can always set default locking option to **Edited record** to avoid editing/inserting same record in same table.

Comment: I see. Then how should I configure my code such that if two users simultaneously executes the code, 1 user selects one record in the table to add new, and another user selects the next record in the table to add new? 
 
A little background - I initially thought MS Access could overcome the problem of simultaneously choosing the lastrow in updating a spreadsheet. So that is what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: You don't _select a record to add a new_. You just add a new record. A table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for clarifying! so that means even if 10 users use the .addnew method simultaneously there will be no conflict? MS Access will automatically slot all 10 records into the table - since they are all "new" records and I am not editing any existing records in the table?

Comment: Yes. And they are not "new" records, whatever that is, just new records.